# Dynamic creation of ionic ion-slide

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework to make my first product on mobiles. I am trying to show a large block of text in different pages using ion-slide-box. But, the text is very dynamic, it can be anything and any number of characters. The page should not have vertical sliding. So, I have to find a way to calculate number of ion-slides required to show the entire text in as many pages (slides) as required. Is there a way in ionic or angularjs to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you please provide some code or mock up of what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I do not have the code yet. The requirement is, I have a web-service that gives me text which I have to show on the devices in full page. If the text is exceeding the screen space, I have to make another slide or scroll view horizontally right to the current view to show remaining text. This way, users can scroll right or left to read the text.